# How to tracka page and all posts with specific tag?

Tags: google-analytics

How can I create a goal which will track defined page and all posts (wordpress) with specific tag? For example... I want to track page livespot.pl/gw2/ and all posts with "gw2" tag. I know how to do it in php which will check for is that a post with that tag or not... but I need help with google analytics part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use even tracking like this.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Visit', 'gw2']);
```

See [The Event Tracker Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) for more examples. This is done is javascript.

You could also use custom variables as seen here [Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables).

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'Tag',           // The top-level name for your online content categories.  Required parameter.
      'gw2',  // Sets the value of "Section" to "Life & Style" for this particular aricle.  Required parameter.
      3                    // Sets the scope to page-level.  Optional parameter.
   ]);
```

Comment: How can I add it to the website? Just copy that in <script></script> on pages that I want to include?

Comment: You will need to use PHP to change the tag that the javascript sends and then yes.

Comment: Just an FYI over the next 2 years Google is in the process of migrating their classic analytics to Universal Analtyics. The code for event tracking and custom variables in Universal Analytics is different then classic. Like I said, it's no rush yet but depending on how you're going to implement the code it might be worth upgrading and using the new code. More info: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/